# install libsoup on macbook pro

Tags: macos, terminal, bash, command-line

I have a shell script from a open source project, when I run it in terminal, I get the following error:

```
./configure: line 17678: syntax error near unexpected token `soup,'
./configure: line 17678: `  PKG_CHECK_MODULES(soup, libsoup-2.4)'
```

I googled on ineternet, someone encountered a similar problem, he suggested to install **libsoup development package** which might fix this problem. Then, I found the [libsoup link](https://wiki.gnome.org/LibSoup).

But I am not sure how to install **libsoup** on my MacBook ? Anyone could help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [macport](http://www.macports.org/install.php) (see the link for download & installation) :

`sudo port install libsoup`